# Do external script redirects without .js extension work on all browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script snippet on third party websites like this:

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/a" async></script>
```

This opens this php file:

```
header('Location: https://storage.googleapis.com/example/example.js', true, 301);
```

My question is, will this work properly on all browsers? In the same way as something like this would:

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/a.js" async></script>
```

If not, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File extensions are irrelevant in URLs. Content-Type matters, the text of the URL does not.

Comment: So it will execute the javascript file normally? As javascript?